# How to let a Python script use the latest available version on this machine?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I put

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.1
```

as the shebang line of a Python script.  What should I change this to so when Python 4.0 is available on a machine, where this script may be run from, it will use python 4.0 instead of any particular older version?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28missile%29#Python-4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't realistically make the script work with the next major version *right now* (because it's likely to break stuff, like 2->3 update did). You can make it use any 3.x version by saying `#!/usr/bin/env python3`.

Comment: @user001: Well, you can use `python` instead of `python2`, which should point to a default interpreter, which *might* be the newest one, but there's no way to tell "use always the newest major version". You'd need a separate script (shell or whatnot) to detect that.